# JSONRPC format different between Jsonrpc4j and go's rpc/jsonrpc

Tags: java, json, go, jsonrpc4j

I was meet a problem when I tried used net/jsonrpc package to build a server and a Java client with jsonrpc4j

The problem is jsonrpc4j is when error happen, golang`s method will return error and encoding to json.

I got this json object in client

> {"id": -6028374044949000, "result": null, "error": "some error return message"}

This object cast failed in java's json4j.

http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification#error_object

After I checked the jsonrpc page, it is said the error field MUST a json object with fields [code, message, date], the golang jsonrpc package not meet the require.

So I`m confused how to solve this.
Change the jsonrpc lib,
Just replace the rpc way to thrift/gRpc,
Avoid to return error but send error in reply and let Java check the response,
Or just edited the json4j or golang's source code ( I'm very horrible about this option)

Thanks for watch.

Comment: em...but it matchs `http://json-rpc.org/wiki/specification`

Comment: the error object detail is added in 2.0

Comment: so i think `net/rpc/jsonrpc` is under 1.0, while it is not documented.

Answer (score 0):

If you need JSON-RPC 2.0 support for Go you can try https://github.com/powerman/rpc-codec

Comment: Thanks, I am instead it of  http and thirft.